# How to make occur mode select the window of buffer `*Occur*`?

Tags: window, occur

Is it possible to make the `occur` mode grab the cursor `(point)`?, right now when I do `M-x occur` and search anything in a buffer, it will open the new buffer with the findings but the cursor stays in the buffer instead going to the findings.

I have to do `C-x 0` to go to the other buffer every time I do a search.

I tried doing it with a blank `init.el` just in case is `helm` or some other package, but I haven't been able to make it focus the cursor on the new buffer.

(I know that there's the `helm-occur` that does that, but is it possible with any command or function to make the cursor change to the active buffer when that command opens a new buffer? )

Comment: The correct way to navigate is to use `M-g M-n` and `M-g M-p` bindings to jump to each occurrence of your search term without jumping to the \*Occur\* buffer. I learnt that trick from [here](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/searching-buffers-occur-mode).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Occur has a hook, `occur-hook`, that contains a list of functions to run after a match is found. So we can add a hook to jump to the `*Occur*` window there:

```
(add-hook 'occur-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (switch-to-buffer-other-window "*Occur*")))
```

Comment: Awesome!. It works perfectly. So, I can use `switch-to-buffer-other-window` with anything that exposes a hook. Can I?.

Comment: Sure, as long as you know the name of the buffer you want to switch to. You can call *any* function from *any* hook. That isn't guaranteed to be a good idea in all cases, but it's up to you to decide! You have to pay special attention to when the hook is called - some are called in advance of a function, some after it runs. The name and/or the documentation string usually explain this for a particular hook.